# SetHidden not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, function

I am trying to show a label for some seconds when i press a button. But the hide function is not working properly.

```
-(void) hide_label:(NSString *)value{
    [value setHidden:YES];

}
```

Get the error: No Visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'setHidden:'.

Comment: Your error message is accurate you are trying to setHidden on an NSString not a UILabel, you need a reference to the UILabel.

Comment: You should really practice to say things more precisely. There is no "hide function". There is an instance method called "hide_label:", and there is a property named "hidden". By not saying precisely what you mean, you keep us guessing. Worse, it is not true that something "is not working properly". It doesn't compile. Totally different. By saying "it is not working", you guide everyone onto a totally wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `value` is an `NSString`, not the `UILabel`. `NSString`'s have no `setHidden:` method, as the error message suggests.

Instead, you will want to pass in the label itself and then call `setHidden:`.

So, change the method to:

```
- (void) hide_label:(UILabel *)label {
  [label setHidden:YES];
}
```

And change all parts of the code that call this method to pass in the UILabel.

Comment: Cool thanks! But when i am to call this function now. i do
    [self hide_label:red_label];
And then i just get an error saying: Incompatible pointer tupes sending UILabel* to parameter of tupe NSString?

Comment: That means you didn't change the method declaration to request a UILabel like I showed. Make sure your method is declared exactly like I have above (Also make sure the `- (void) hide_label:(UILabel *)label` part is in your Header file.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` is **not** a subclass of `UILabel` and does not respond to `setHidden:` you must call that on the `UILabel` property itself.

---

How do you declare your `UILabel`? It should be something similar to the following if you connect via a nib:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

or if its created programatically:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;
```

You can then call setHidden on the label, as it is a property you can use dot syntax:

```
label.hidden = YES;
```

You can check its state by using its accessor:

```
if ([label isHidden]) {
  //... do something 
}
```

It might be worth you reading some tutorials on iOS development, [Look Here on raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)